# When I doing some animation in MotionLayout with RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout that thing getting weird

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, android-motionlayout

I was using MotionLayout to achieve some cool effect when RecyclerView drag up, but it looks like when I want to use SwipeRefreshLayout with RecyclerView, things getting conflict.

If no SwipeRefreshLayout, it was fine

If I surround with SwipeRefreshLayout, drag up behavior was weird like opposed

https://gist.github.com/GHChrisSu/6aadf40dc693bc47cbb83a167a82a4b9

And the motion scene is below

https://gist.github.com/GHChrisSu/a154d59f34555cccfc1b48617989ae16

Comment: https://gist.github.com/GHChrisSu/6aadf40dc693bc47cbb83a167a82a4b9

Comment: Please add your gist link to your question body.

Comment: Please post your MotionScene as well.

Comment: Thanks, I already put it to gist.

Comment: Any updates to this? I am trying to solve this issue as well.

Answer (score 7):

You should wrap your `MotionLayout` in a `SwipeRefreshLayout` like this:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
                android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutDescription="@xml/play_scene">

                <!-- Some xml code -->

            </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then you must add a `MotionLayout.TransitionListener` to your `MotionLayout` to `enable/disable` your `SwipeRefreshLayout` depending on the `MotionLayout` state.

```
binding.motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object :MotionLayout.TransitionListener{
        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
            Log.d("RepairsFragment","$p1 $p2 $p3")
            if (p3 == 0f) {
                binding.refresh.isEnabled=true
            } else {
                binding.refresh.isEnabled = false
                binding.refresh.isRefreshing=false
            }
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: You can write this as `binding.refresh.isEnabled = p3 == 0`

Comment: onTransitionChange not called when fast scrolling, anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve this by wrap the SwipeRefreshLayout out of the motionlayout, and change the state of SwipeRefreshLayout in onTransitionChange function to deal with this issue

Comment: Kindly more detail.

Comment: detect the motion layout callback

Comment: I try many way; it still no luck. I think I miss the logic now.