# ViewPager within MotionLayout not scrolling correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-motionlayout

I have a MotionLayout which basically contains an image and a ViewPager. The ViewPager renders a fragment with a RecyclerView in it.
At first the image has normal size, when i drag up, the image reduces its size and the ViewPager (with the RecyclerView within it) expands.

The problem is that the **MotionLayout keeps intercepting the scroll action**, so if the RecyclerView is expanded, and the user scrolls down, the MotionLayout will expand the image, **rather than letting the RecyclerView scroll**.

What i would expect is that the MotionLayout will expand the top image only if the RecyclerView has reached the first element, in that case since the RecyclerView cannot scroll anymore, the scroll action would be managed by the MotionLayout.

I am aware that within MotionLayout I can set the attribute **moveWhenScrollAtTop="true"** to get that behaviour, but that only works if there is just a RecyclerView, but not if the RecyclerView is within a ViewPager.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: In case someone has the same problem and bumps into my question, please read: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922207/motion-layout-with-swipe-gesture-swiperefreshlayout-recyclerview-bug-wrong-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922207/motion-layout-with-swipe-gesture-swiperefreshlayout-recyclerview-bug-wrong-b) This is a bug and an issue has been created at google's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

if your xml file  contains nested scrollview just add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"